# can i stick a regular html page in an asp.net mvc site . 

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there anyway to do this?  if so what would the controller code look like to point to a specific html file instead of a MVC View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need any Controller code for static HTML page. All you need, add link to HTML page in necessary View (<a href="<%=Url.Content(~/Html/Page1.html)%>">Link to html page</a>)

Comment: what if i want this file in the same directory as my other Views ?

Comment: No problem. Place them into Views folder and use Url.Content(~/Vievs/.../Page1.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
public ActionResult SomeOtherPage()
{
   return Redirect("/Some/Page.htm");
}
```