# What's the differences in cshtml and html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'll want to create a project using MVC and angular and i thought about using html like templates.
This is the best practices? 
And If i use html, i'll lose security in my application, or other things beyond Razor?

Comment: There's no "best practice". If you want to take some load off your server, do as much as you can in javascript client side with angular. If you'd rather create the html server side (for example you have different outputs depending on which role the user is in), perhaps razor is the better choice. The answer is: it depends

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/2032101.aspx?What+is+the+difference+between+cshtml+and+html+

Comment: Okay.. Thanks Alexander Derck!!

Comment: Related: [Using Html instead of csHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046247/using-html-instead-of-cshtml); I'd recommend editing this question to remove "best practices" and maybe (?) flagging this question as a dupe of the question I linked. I found this by searching for something very similar to the title of this question. Lucas, if you're still here I strongly recommend avoiding asking about "best practices" on SE sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cshtml is basically razor view extension and any view renders in html finally.
You need to use Razor in your application as it supports server side code but raw html does not.